# Selecting li tag with specific anchor tag text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code :

```
<ul id="ulId">
    <div>
        <div>
             <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">4RUNNER</a></li>
             <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">86</a></li>
             <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">AVALON</a></li>
        </div>
   </div>
</ul>
```

I want to add class active to `li` with specific anchor text, e.g I want to add class active to li element whose anchor tag text is "4RUNNER".

I have tried the following code but it's not working :

```
$("#ulId li").find('a:contains(4RUNNER)').addClass('active')
```

Comment: Well you are adding the class to the anchor.

Comment: Yes, i want to add it to li .@epascarello

Comment: So why are you selecting the anchor?

Comment: For comparing text. Actually i want to add class to that li which has specific anchor text .@epascarello

Comment: So why not just use contains on the li? Still will have the same text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you're adding the class `active` to the anchor itself, you need to use the jQuery method **[`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** to go up to the parent node `li` then add the class :

```js
$("#ulId li").find('a:contains(4RUNNER)').parent().addClass('active');
//Or
// $("#ulId li").find('a:contains(4RUNNER)').closest('li').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulId">
  <div>
    <div>
      <li class="cModel active" style=""><a href="#">4RUNNER</a></li>
      <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">86</a></li>
      <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">AVALON</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the current selector is the anchor, you can use `parent()` to target the parent `li` to add the class:

```js
$("#ulId li").find('a:contains(4RUNNER)').parent().addClass('active')
```

```css
.active a{
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulId">
    <div>
        <div>
             <li class="cModel active" style=""><a href="#">4RUNNER</a></li>
             <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">86</a></li>
             <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">AVALON</a></li>
        </div>
   </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** or **[`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)** or **[`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)** of jquery.

```js
/*------------------closest()--------------------*/
$("#ulId li").find('a:contains(4RUNNER)').closest("li").addClass('active');

/*------------------parents()--------------------*/
$("#ulId li").find('a:contains(4RUNNER)').parents("li").addClass('active')

/*------------------parent()--------------------*/
$("#ulId li").find('a:contains(4RUNNER)').parent().addClass('active');
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ulId">
    <div>
        <div>
             <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">4RUNNER</a></li>
             <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">86</a></li>
             <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">AVALON</a></li>
        </div>
   </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is adding it to the anchor and not the li. You can simply just use contains on the li element since it will have the same text as the anchor.

```js
$("#ulId li:contains(4RUNNER)").addClass('active')
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="ulId">
    <div>
        <div>
             <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">4RUNNER</a></li>
             <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">86</a></li>
             <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">AVALON</a></li>
        </div>
   </div>
</ul>
```

If you really want to use find, than you need to select the parent with `...find(...).parent()` or `...find(...).closest('li')`.